# Hyperledger fabric transaction

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

I just started learning Hyperledger fabric. Now I am using fabric-samples first-network. how can I make a new transaction in the network? and do I need to have a chain code in hyperledger fabric network to make transaction? and how can I see transactions time in log file? And how can i make to run transactions for like 30 mins in the network.

in /scripts/utills.sh file I found that there is invoke transaction, but I don't understand what it's doing.

I expected to have a test network where I can change some blockchain parameters and test it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. You need to have a chaincode to do a transaction. I suggest you to go through main concepts of Hyperledger Fabric like CA, MSP, Orderer, Chaincode etc before tyring with the transactions. You'll get a much better understanding of how Fabric functions.
After this you can go through the simple tutorial provided by Fabric with the samples and their explanation for each step. Its pretty well explained.